# Exponential Decay on nolinear Schrodinger type equation with negative potential

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, big-list, elliptic-pde

Given a unbounded domain  $\Omega$(a region or an open manifold) with $\dim \geq3$, consider the equation
$$A u+Vu+|u|^ku=0,$$
here $A=\sum_{ij}\partial_ia^{ij}(x)\partial_j$ is an elliptic operator with smooth coefficients.  Suppose  that $A+V$ is the semi positive Laplacian, here  $V$ is a (smooth) function with $V<0$, we may assume that $V$ is bounded. 
Assume there is the solution  $u$ with $u\in L^2(\Omega)$.

**Q**
I just want to ask if there are some work or results to study the exponential decay of $u$, i.e. $\int_\Omega |u|^2\exp(h)<\infty$, here $h$ is a distance function.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment.

Your question really needs to be stated more precisely.

First, presumably there are conditions on the dimension $d$, on the geometry of $\Omega$, and on behavior of $V$. Absent these conditions certainly exponential decay cannot be expected.

(You probably also want to give a boundary condition.)

For example, in dimension 1, the equation 
$$ - u'' + |u|^2 u - \frac{3x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} u = 0 $$
is of the type you are looking for, by admits the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ solution 
$$ u = (1 + x^2)^{-1/2} $$
that does not decay exponentially.

Related to this point is the fact that the exponential decay of solutions to *linear* Schrodinger operators are usually proven for the eigenvalue problem where the eigenvalue has a non-zero real part. There are some classical works of Agmon ([this](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=745286), [this](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=819005), and [this](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=956950) for example) in this case. Is it the case that you want $V$ to be non-zero at infinity?

*[Following paragraph is struck since the OP edited to fix it]* <strike>Secondly, your definition of "exponential decay" is odd. Taking for example $h(x) = \ln (1 + \ln(1 + |x|))$, this function grows to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity, but I would not really call functions for which $\int |u|^2 \exp(h) < \infty$ as "exponentially decaying".</strike>

Finally, if you are willing to take the existence of a solution for granted, and if you are willing to guess that the expected solution has *some* decay, then can you not just look at the linear theory, where you look at estimates for decay of the linear equation 
$$ - \triangle u + \tilde{V} u = 0 $$
where $\tilde{V} = V + |u|^k$? You may be able to upgrade slower decay to exponential decay in this case. (For example, if you know $V$ gives a potential well and limits to $-1$ near infinity sufficiently fast, then Agmon's results cited above would imply that any sufficiently fast polynomially decaying solution is in fact decaying exponentially.)